# Position of "ora"

Tags: difference, adverbs, word-order

I read the following sentence in an Italian learning language tool:

> Il paziente ora è fuori pericolo.

Does it have the same meaning of "il paziente è fuori pericolo ora" and are both equally usual?

Comment: Yes IMO they're equivalent and another equivalent sentence is _Ora il paziente è fuori pericolo_. I don't have metrics about the usage, but I think they're all pretty much used the same.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to confirm because that is not so in English ("The patient now is out of danger" is gramatically correct, but it is not usual).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your phrase can be rewritten in many ways, all of them mantaning the same meaning:

> 1. Il paziente **ora** è fuori pericolo.
> 2. Il paziente è fuori pericolo **ora**.
> 3. **Ora** il paziente è fuori pericolo
> 4. Il paziente è **ora** fuori pericolo.

You can find some information about the correct positioning of the adverb in this post *[La posizione dell'avverbio](https://www.lagrammaticaitaliana.it/lezionegrammatica/12.115-la-posizione-dellavverbio.aspx)*:

> Per quanto riguarda la posizione dell'avverbio, generalmente si mette
>   dopo il verbo:
>
> > In questo letto dormo **raramente**.
>
> e prima di un aggettivo o di un altro avverbio :
>
> > Tua zia è **veramente** noiosa.
> >
> > Ho mangiato **molto bene**.

So the general rule is that the position of the adverb is after the verb.

When the adverb refers to a particular element of the phrase, refers to the whole phrase, it can be positioned in every point of the phrase but separated with comma:

> Quando l'avverbio, invece si riferisce a un elemento particolare della
>   frase, si riferisce a tutta la frase nel suo complesso, la sua
>   collocazione può avvenire in qualsiasi punto della frase, dalla quale però risulta separato mediante la virgola:
>
> > **Francamente**, non sono convinta dell'offerta.
> >
> > Non sono convinta, **francamente**, dell'offerta.
> >
> > Non sono convinta dell'offerta, **francamente**.

Comment: We could also add the cases that can be considered "poetic licenses" like _Raramente in questo letto dormo_ ;)